# Moving from one tableview to another tableview

Tags: cocoa, tableview

I have a `tableview` and when i moving from first `tableviw` to another `tableview` it displays the some gap following bt second `tableview`. And another problem is when scroll up the second `tableview` also displays the top item of the first `tableview`. Please tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say what the problem is without seeing your code.  Have you read through the UIViewController programming guide?  They explain in detail how to accomplish this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Answer (score 1):

Did you use different CellIdentifier in the tableViews? `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";`
You should use different names for them because they are static, and the table views may reuse each others cells.